# Is it undefined behaviour to have a reference to freed memory?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, lifetime

In C++, is it undefined behaviour to free memory that is still referred to by a reference, even if that reference is not used again? For example, does the following function invoke undefined behaviour?

```
void foo() {
    std::map<std::string, int> mymap;
    {
        int& val = mymap["eight"];
        val = 8;
        mymap.erase("eight"); // Oops! val still refers to mymap["eight"]
        // val is not used again
    }
    std::cout << "Entry count: " << mymap.size() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: So long as its not used, I believe, it's fine. Consider that a reference doesn't necessarily even have space allocated for it.

Comment: @ChrisMM That makes logical sense. But the language standard doesn't always work in a way that is totally logical.

Comment: Taking a reference to something that doesn't exist is UB. Having a reference to something that used to exist is not UB if you don't use it.

Comment: My impression would be that typically UB is the associated with the behavior of objects and not their state of being. I would argue that unless you use a reference, it has no behavior. It may be hard to quote the standard for this question.

Comment: My *guess* is the standard doesn't explicitly say this *is* well-defined, but instead, never says that it is *not*.

Comment: I think the standard, in section 3.8 (Object lifetime) of C++11 version, paragraph 6, is saying that this is well defined. It talks about glvalues but I think that those include references. But I'm not sure enough about the terminology to post that as an answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

From [associative.reqmts]p9, we see(emphasis mine):

> The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container,
>   and the **erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements**.

This is from N4659 [basic.stc]p4 **<sup>1</sup>** (again, emphasis mine):

> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values (6.9.2). **Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior**. ***Any other use*** of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.

Although the text talks specifically about pointers, there is no reason to believe that it is not applicable to references(well, in a way they can be thought of as pointers). Also note the fact that it says "**`Any other use`**", so as long as you don't use the pointers/references in an expression after it has been invalidated, the behaviour should be well defined.

**<sup>1</sup>** Note: Looks like this text was added in N4659 and doesn't seem to be present in earlier versions of the standard.

Answer (score -4):

> Is it undefined behaviour to have a reference to freed memory?

The standard doesn't define any behaviour for "having" any value of any type.

---

> ```
> mymap.erase("eight"); // Oops! val still refers to mymap["eight"]
> ```

This is what the standard says about behaviour of `erase`:

> [associative.reqmts] ... The erase members shall invalidate ... references to the erased elements ...

Note that the rule does not say that behaviour is undefined if those references exist. In fact, it would be rather pointless to describe that those references are invalidated if the existence of the reference would always imply undefined behaviour.

As for definition of what an invalid reference is... the standard appears to be lacking. There is a definition for invalid pointer, but I cannot find any for invalid reference. This lack of definition could be considered to be a defect in the standard.

Comment: That answer would carry more weight if supported by Standard quote, as is customary in `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: @SergeyA Sometimes there just isn't a quote. As far as I know, there are no rules for "having" a reference to have any behaviour. Undefined or otherwise. Should I quote all the rules of the standard in order to conclude that none of them say that it is UB?

Comment: @eerorika If the standard doesn't explicitly define something then it is undefined behvaiour. That is literally what "undefined" means! So if there is no relevant rule in the standard then it is indeed undefined behaviour. But actually I think the "object lifetime" section might cover this anyway.

Comment: Indeed, this might be a hard, or even unanswerable question. But the point being made is that this is not an appropriate answer for the given tags.

Comment: @ArthurTacca `If the standard doesn't explicitly define something then it is undefined behvaiour` Not at all. Standard doesn't explicitly define that a program that has an integer with value 42 can have well defined behvaviour. That doesn't mean that program that has an integer with value would always have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @eerorika I am not a language-lawyering expert, but I believe you actually could find a collection of rules in the standard that show that is well-defined. It may not mention the specific value 42 exactly, but it would for example cover the minimum permissible range of values that must be storable in an integer, or at least say that it is implementation defined.

Comment: @eerorika For example, section 3.9.1 (fundamental types) of C++11 standard talks about the standard integer (and other types), and mentions the header `climits` as defining the sizes. That header is automatically taken from the C standard which includes required ranges in 2.2.4.2 (numeric limits) of C89, such as "* minimum value for an object of type int INT_MIN -32767". Of course you also need other parts of the standard such as object definitions and initialisation.

Comment: With regard to your edit: I don't think the language necessarily means that. Partly it's saying "no really, this does actually erase the elements" in language-lawyery terms. Partly it contrasts with e.g. vector which says "Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase." The map one is assuring you that it is only invalidating references to the erased elements, unlike vector which also invalidates references to specified *other* elements.

Comment: @ArthurTacca And it doesn't say that existence of those references has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @eerorika perhaps, this answer can not be answered. The answer can be that the standard lacks any definition. Or you might simply refrain from answering :) The tag used demands authoritative references for answers, in my view.

Comment: @SergeyA The std is a joke. It isn't a language spec, not even close. (And there is zero description of the behavior of threads.)